# Only select Form Input tags that have form-data in them using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to only select `<input>` tags that **are being filled** / that **have been filled** in by the user, using CSS?

Comment: question is not clear..

Comment: The question says “have been filled in by the user”, but a comment says that you want “to select the `input` that is being filled in by the use”. You should clarify what you mean, by editing the question. Telling *why* you want to do this might help in understanding what you want.

Comment: sorry! I hope the question is clearer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you mean, you have an `<input>` tag with an attribute `form-data`, you can do this way:

```
input[form-data]
```

Or, if you need to select the inputs that have to be filled in by the user that are empty on the first run, you can either set a class to them like:

```
<input class="user-data" />
```

And use CSS to select `.user-data`. If not, you can use JavaScript to find all the inputs with 0 length and you can add a class `user-data` like above and select the inputs by:

```
.user-data
```

Or, if you want to select however, you can do this way in modern browsers:

```
input[value=""]
```

Comment: what I want to do is to select the `input` that is being filled in by the user. For example I want to select the **Name:** field as the user enters his/her name?

Comment: @Praadhaan Use `input:focus` may be?

Comment: No not only when the the user is filling it but after he/she has moved to another field as well. `input:focus` allows me to select the element only while the user is entering the data. thanks though

Comment: So you need to use my JavaScript solution! There's no pure CSS solution to manipulate the DOM Objects.